# How to join two json object and delete also in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var myObj = [
    { "heading":"Enter Name", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"name1" },
    { "heading":"Enter Phone", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"phone1" }
];

var anotherObj=[
    { "heading":"Enter Name", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"name2" },
    { "heading":"Enter Phone", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"phone2" }
];
```

I want to join these two: that is:

```
[{ "heading":"Enter Name", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"name1" },
 { "heading":"Enter Phone", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"phone1" },
 { "heading":"Enter Name", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"name2" },
 { "heading":"Enter Phone", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"phone2" }];
```

where `"fieldid":"name1"==> 1` means table row no 1 
`"fieldid":"name2"==> 2` means table row no 2

Also I want to delete operation, suppose I delete 2nd row then the JSON will

```
[{ "heading":"Enter Name", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"name1" },
 { "heading":"Enter Phone", "data_type":"text", "fieldid":"phone1" }];
```

Comment: Please, properly format this code

Comment: Can't make head nor tail of this without proper formatting.

Comment: To the OP please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @Liam it's not that difficult, but unless it's something minor, I'd say OP should do it.

Comment: This was pretty minor...It took me about 5 seconds...

Comment: Welcome to SO @Mr.Prakash Mondal. Prior to asking questions, you should visit this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var result = myObj.concat(anotherObj);
```

To join the objects, and then filter to delete the row you want

```
result = result.filter(x => x.fieldid != 'name2')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the variable names are not relevant.  `myObj` and `anotherObj` are arrays of objects.  So basically, you need to combine two arrays.

You can use:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1,arr2); 
console.log(arr1);  // final merged result will be in arr1
```

Hope it helps

To delete, you can use:

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

Check splice reference for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
// concat arrays to have all data in one place
var sumArray = myObj.concat(anotherObj);

// delete 1 element starts from index 2
sumArray.splice(2, 1);
```

You should read more about operations with arrays here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you can join two arrays with [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)() and remove elements from them with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)().

```js
var myObj = [{
    "heading": "Enter Name",
    "data_type": "text",
    "fieldid": "name1"
  },
  {
    "heading": "Enter Phone",
    "data_type": "text",
    "fieldid": "phone1"
  }
];

var anotherObj = [{
    "heading": "Enter Name",
    "data_type": "text",
    "fieldid": "name2"
  },
  {
    "heading": "Enter Phone",
    "data_type": "text",
    "fieldid": "phone2"
  }
];

function join(obj1, obj2) {
  return obj1.concat(obj2);

}

function removeRow(obj, row) {
  obj.splice((row - 1) * 2, 2);
  return obj;
}

var joined = join(myObj, anotherObj);
console.log("Join:", joined);
console.log("Remove 2. row:", removeRow(joined, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    var x = myObj.concat(anotherObj);

    x = x.filter(function (item) {

    if(item.fieldid != 'name2' && item.fieldid != 'phone2')
    {
        return item;
    }
});

console.log(x);
```